# How can I make a typedef or alias for a template function that can also be used in friend function declarations?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

If I have something like this:

#### mytemplates.h

```cpp
#ifndef MYTEMPLATES_H
#define MYTEMPLATES_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class BaseClass;
// Alias (non-working) version:
//class DerivedClass1;

namespace MyTemplates
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> object_up;
    
    template<typename SomeDerivedClass>
    object_up createFromIntFloat(int intParam, float floatParam)
    {
        SomeDerivedClass *newObject_raw = new SomeDerivedClass(intParam, floatParam);

        object_up uniqueObject {newObject_raw};

        std::cout << "createFromIntFloat." << "\n";

        return uniqueObject;
    }
    // Alias (non-working) version:
    //using createFromIntFloatPtrType = object_up(*)(int intParam, float floatParam);

    template<typename SomeDerivedClass>
    object_up createFromString(std::string stringParam)
    {
        SomeDerivedClass *newObject_raw = new SomeDerivedClass(stringParam);

        object_up uniqueObject {newObject_raw};

        std::cout << "createFromString." << "\n";

        return uniqueObject;
    }
    // Alias (non-working) version:
    //using createFromStringPtrType = object_up(*)(std::string stringParam);  

    // Alias (non-working) version:
    // createFromStringPtrType createDerivedClass1 =  createFromString<DerivedClass1>;
}

#endif // MYTEMPLATES_H
```

#### baseclass.h

```cpp
#ifndef BASECLASS_H
#define BASECLASS_H

class BaseClass
{
protected:
    BaseClass(){};
};

#endif // BASECLASS_H
```

#### derivedclass1.h

```cpp
#ifndef DERIVEDCLASS1_H
#define DERIVEDCLASS1_H

#include "baseclass.h"
#include "mytemplates.h"

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
    std::string stringParam;
protected:
    DerivedClass1(std::string aStringParam) : BaseClass(), stringParam(aStringParam) {};

    // Alias (non-working) version:
    // friend MyTemplates::object_up MyTemplates::createDerivedClass1(std::string stringParam);

    // Non-alias version:
    friend MyTemplates::object_up MyTemplates::createFromString<DerivedClass1>(std::string stringParam);
};

#endif // DERIVEDCLASS1_H
```

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "mytemplates.h"
#include "derivedclass1.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Alias (non-working) version:
    // MyTemplates::object_up uniqueClass1 = MyTemplates::createDerivedClass1("creation info for class 1");
    
    // Non-alias version:
    MyTemplates::object_up uniqueClass1 = MyTemplates::createFromString<DerivedClass1>("creation info for class 1");
}
```

I would like to create some kind of alias like the *Alias (non-working) version* on the above code so that I could use this alias - **createDerivedClass1** - both in direct calling like in *main.cpp* and in friend declarations like in *derivedclass1.h*

How can I change the code above from the *Non-alias version* to the *Alias version* and make it work?

Comment: `createDerivedClass1` is a function pointer, so `friend` declaration is wrong and useless. So your global variable should be defined only once (or be `inline`).

Comment: @Jarod42 So how can I make _createFromString<DerivedClass1>_ access DerivedClass1 protected ctor?

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I believe I see now: I keep the original (non-alias version) of the friend declaration and use the alias version elsewhere, right?

Comment: `createDerivedClass1` (which might be `const`/`constexpr`) just "calls" `createFromString<DerivedClass1>` so doesn't need extra access. You might uncomment all but the friend declaration. (and fix ODR for your global).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are for types because types are not first class objects in C++. But you do not need aliases for plain functions because you can simply use function pointers.

But a function pointer is just a pointer and you must declare the real function to be friend. It all boil down to:

```
...
class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
    std::string stringParam;
protected:
    DerivedClass1(std::string aStringParam) : BaseClass(), stringParam(aStringParam) {};

    // Alias (non-working) version:
    //friend MyTemplates::object_up MyTemplates::createDerivedClass1(std::string stringParam);

    // Non-alias version:
    friend MyTemplates::object_up MyTemplates::createFromString<DerivedClass1>(std::string stringParam);
};

namespace MyTemplates {
    object_up(*createDerivedClass1)(std::string) = createFromString<DerivedClass1>;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Alias (non-working) version:
    MyTemplates::object_up uniqueClass1 = MyTemplates::createDerivedClass1("creation info for class 1");

    // Non-alias version:
    MyTemplates::object_up uniqueClass2 = MyTemplates::createFromString<DerivedClass1>("creation info for class 1");
}
```

Comment: This solution worked flawlessly in my example code but when I tried to transpose this solution to my real code I am getting an "allocation of incomplete type 'DerivedClass1''" equivalent erorr message. I only get it when using the alias. With the non-alias version, it works fine. Any ideas? Unfortunately I am not managing to produce a simplified version of the code with this last error.

Comment: @Rsevero: Here I only declared and used the pointer to func **after** the definition of `DerivedClass1` and did not try to use it in that definition. Any attempt to use it differently will raise an error similar to the one you describe.

Comment: I moved the declaration of the pointer func to _MyTemplates.cpp_ and it worked fine. Thanks!